# ¿Por qué el error con mi herencia?

Tags: c++

Realizando un trabajo de asignar *nombres*, *edad*, *código* y *nota* cuando trato de  asignar una herencia para luego un `set` con `AlumnoH`, me sale un error. Pienso que puede ser la manera en que lo estoy heredando pero la verdad no tengo mucha idea, el error dice que falta un `'{'`(sí, disculpen, este error me lo daba en la linea de void AlumnoH::setValue2(string _name, int _age, string _codigo, float _notafinal) : Persona(_name, _age){}, justo donde dice : Persona(_name, _age), exactamente en el ':') para que esté correcto, pero no creo que sea el problema. En un ejemplo que vi no necesitaban de eso.

Si pudieran de paso recomendarme algo para repasar esa parte, estaría más que genial. Gracias!

herencia.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "herencia.h"
using namespace std;


Persona::Persona(){}

void Persona::setValue(string _name, int _age){
    this-> name = _name;
    this-> age = _age;
}
const string Persona::getName() const{
    return name;
}
const int Persona::getAge() const{
    return age;
}

void AlumnoH::setValue2(string _name, int _age, string _codigo, float _notafinal) : Persona(_name, _age){
    this-> codigo = _codigo;
    this-> notafinal = _notafinal;
}


Persona::~Persona(){}
```

herencia.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Persona{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Persona();
    virtual ~Persona();
    Persona(string, int);
    virtual ~Persona();
    void setValue(string _name, int _age);
    const string getName() const;
    const int getAge() const;
};

class AlumnoH : public Persona{
private: 
    string codigo;
    float notafinal;
public:
    AlumnoH();
    virtual ~AlumnoH();
    
    void setValue2(string, int, string, float) : Persona(string, int);
    const string getName() const;
    const int getAge() const;
    const string getCodigo() const;
    const float getNotafinal() const;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "herencia.h"
using namespace std;

template<typename T>

void print(T objeto){
    cout << objeto.getName() << endl;
    cout << objeto.getAge() << endl;
}


int main(){
    Persona P1;
    P1.setValue("Hernan", 12);
    print(P1);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que haces una herencia en el metodo:

```
void setValue(string _name, int _age);
```

Este recibe parametros, pero lo ideal seria enivar esos paramametros al constructor directamente;

```
Persona::Persona(){}
```

Veo que tienes el constructor vacio de persona y estas heredando a un metodo el contrcutor de persona, lo cual ocurre el error de herencia , lo ideal seria lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "herencia.h"
using namespace std;


Persona::Persona(string _name,int _age){
    this-> name = _name;
    this-> age = _age;
}

const string Persona::getName() const{
    return name;
}
const int Persona::getAge() const{
    return age;
}

vAlumnoH::vAlumnoH(string _name, int _age, string _codigo, float 
 _notafinal) : Persona(_name, _age){
    this-> codigo = _codigo;
    this-> notafinal = _notafinal;
}


Persona::~Persona(){}
```

Es lo mas recomedable de hacer

Answer (score 0):

En base a la información de [este compilador](https://godbolt.org/z/hf6cxvYov):

- Estás declarando 2 veces el destructor:

  ```
  virtual ~Persona();
  ```
- Puedes delegar constructores pero no funciones. Lo que sí puede hacer es llamar a funciones del padre así:

  ```
  void AlumnoH::setValue2(string _name, int _age, string _codigo, float _notafinal){
      Persona::setValue(_name, _age); // <---
      this-> codigo = _codigo;
      this-> notafinal = _notafinal;
  }
  ```

  Además de que no existe el constructor `Persona(string, int)`.
- Delegar una función es un detalle de la implementación. Por lo que no debes escribir la delegación como parte de la declaración. Por ejemplo, agregas un constructor a `Persona`:

  ```
  // Declaración
  Persona(string, int);

  // Definición
  Persona(string, int) : Persona() {
     ...
  }
  ```

  De hecho, como la declaración solo necesita nombre, parámetros y tipo de retorno, si la escribes como:

  ```
  Persona(string, int) : Persona();
  ```

  El compilador interpreta que estás dando una definición. Por eso dice `expected '{' or ','`. Porque espera el cuerpo de la función.

---

El archivo `herencia.h` te quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Persona{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Persona();
    virtual ~Persona();
    Persona(string, int);
    void setValue(string _name, int _age);
    const string getName() const;
    const int getAge() const;
};

class AlumnoH : public Persona{
private: 
    string codigo;
    float notafinal;
public:
    AlumnoH();
    virtual ~AlumnoH();
    
    void setValue2(string, int, string, float);
    const string getName() const;
    const int getAge() const;
    const string getCodigo() const;
    const float getNotafinal() const;
};
```